# Managing and finding variables in Clojure REPL

Tags: clojure

I was looking at https://github.com/juxt/dirwatch library. The example from the front page is:

```
(require '[juxt.dirwatch :refer (watch-dir)])
(watch-dir println (clojure.java.io/file "/tmp"))
```

That works fine. Let's say the above is executed in REPL:

```
user=> (watch-dir println (clojure.java.io/file "/tmp"))
#<Agent@16824c93: #<LinuxWatchService sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService@17ece9ac>>
```

Now, I have an agent that will print events when I modify files in `/tmp`:

```
{:file #<File /tmp/1>, :count 1, :action :modify}
```

so all is fine.

I know I can reference the agent by using previous expression references (`*1`, `*2` and `*3`). However, I don't know how to, without restarting the REPL itself:

- Unbind an implicit var created like this - i.e. how to remove the binding completely, so that agent gets GCed and stops working
- Access it in case I lost it in cases where I did not bind it, such as the above. If I'm not mistaken, in REPL only the last three results are available (`*3` is, but `*4` and further are not), at least per http://clojure.org/repl_and_main

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the code? The documentation to `watch-dir` has this: "The watcher returned by this function is a resource which
should be closed with close-watcher."

Looking at the code, it `watch-dir` uses [`send-off`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/send-off), which "Dispatch a potentially blocking action to an agent. Returns the agent immediately.". In other words, to address your first question, there is no implicit var created. If you want to get rid of the agent, you should bind the returned agent to some var and call `close-watcher` on it afterwards.

To address the second question, take a look at the canonical [documentation for agents](https://clojure.org/reference/agents). Specifically, you can call [`shutdown-agents`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/shutdown-agents), which will shut-down the thread pool (potentially killing other agents as well).